# jquery, work on a control after finding it by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, controls

i found a required control with jquery like below...

the control source:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvImages_ctrl0_ctrl3_lbEdit" class="lbEdit" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rlvImages$ctrl0$ctrl3$lbEdit','')">ویرایش</a>
```

the jquery code:

> alert($('a[id$="lbEdit"]'));

---

i want to know what is the difference between

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvImages_ctrl0_ctrl3_lbEdit
```

and

```
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rlvImages$ctrl0$ctrl3$lbEdit
```

and how can i get

```
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rlvImages$ctrl0$ctrl3$lbEdit
```

with jquery?
mean i need to check the upper id or whatever in a condition and i think hardcode the upper id is not the correct way ...

Comment: @mcgrailm -> what is your mean?

Comment: I just don't understand that id. i guess I should be glad i dont' use asp seems to me id should be simple

Comment: @mcgrailm It's one of the little bugbears I always had about ASP.Net Webforms. MVC allows you full control of every part of the HTML markup and is a much better environment to work in IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvImages_ctrl0_ctrl3_lbEdit` is the HTML Id attribute of the element.

`ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rlvImages$ctrl0$ctrl3$lbEdit` is the internal ASP.Net reference of the element. It has no use to the front-end of the site.

In your example, to get the text of that element using a jQuery selector, you would use:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvImages_ctrl0_ctrl3_lbEdit").text();
```

It's also worth noting that using ASP.Net webforms will mean that you cannot rely on the ID of that element being that same forever. You would have to pinpoint that specific element via it's class (which you can set reliably in ASP.Net) and it's parent(s).

Comment: dear @Rory McCrossan -> thanks for answer - but .text() does not return ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rlvImages$ctrl0$ctrl3$lbEdit.i want a way to get this string -> output be that!

Comment: If you want to get that value out (although I can't imagine why you'd need to), then `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvImages_ctrl0_ctrl3_lbEdit").attr("href")` will get it. You'll then need to perform a regex replace on it to just get the specific control value.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net uses those convoluted naming patterns to generate html element ids when they're `runat="server"` that make it difficult to use to find a control by id on the page.

Try using this server-tagged selector using the Controls `ClientID` instead:

```
$('#<%=lbEdit.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET 4.0 and set your CliendIDMode to Static.

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

It'll make your IDs a lot easier to reference from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to do this instead.
    javascript:__doPostBack('<%= lbEdit.ClientID %>','')